# addClass to disabled checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to addClass to disabled input field using checkbox. However, the class gets applied to all the checkboxes even the active ones.

How do I correctly add the "red" class to the disabled input and then remove the class once the MAX is less than 2.

```js
var MAX = 2;
    $('input.addnominee').click(function() {
        ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',true):$('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled',false);
        ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('.checkmark').addClass('red'):$('checkmark').removeClass('red');
    });
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
.checkmark.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
```

Comment: check the line ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('.checkmark').addClass('red'):$('checkmark').removeClass('red');     You missed to mention 'dot' operator while removing class 'red'

Comment: There is a pseudo element `:disabled` sorry can't add a link I'm on phone :/

Comment: Here the doc for the `:disabled` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your current code and making small corrections (like using [siblings selector](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)) you get:

```js
var MAX = 2;
$('input.addnominee').click(function() {
  ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true) : $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled', false);
  ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').siblings().addClass('red') : $('input.addnominee').siblings().removeClass('red');
});
```

```css
label {display: block;}
.checkmark.red {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I probably didn't explain properly. The class "red" is to be applied on the disabled checkbox.

Comment: Sure, my bad. Updated the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Got it working finally. Will read up more on siblings function!

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not familiar with ternary I've done this using `if else`, I am removing the `red` class from the checked checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var MAX = 2;
  $('input.addnominee').click(function() {
    if ($('input.addnominee:checked').length < MAX) {
      $('.checkmark').removeClass('red');
    }
    ($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX) ? $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled', true): $('input.addnominee').not(':checked').attr('disabled', false);

    if (($('input.addnominee:checked').length == MAX)) {
      $('.checkmark').addClass('red');
      $('input.addnominee:checked+.checkmark').removeClass('red')
    } else {
      $('checkmark').removeClass('red');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

.checkmark.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
<label class="checkbox"> Add Nominee
  <input class="addnominee" type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark">Hello</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks but the class "red" isn't removed after I unchecked.

Comment: I understand this is marked answered already but could you let me know how to get removeClass working? I'm still learning JS and this would be a great help.

Comment: @ElaineByene I updated my answer to remove the red class when unchecked

Comment: @ElaineByene jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. Currently you are using jQuery in your code. There implemented methods to do the works that we want. As you asked to remove the class you need to call the `removeClass("classname")` function to the element. You can learn more about jQuery here https://jquery.com/ and  javascript https://www.javascript.com/learn/strings

Answer (score 0):

Use below selector to select all disabled inputs :

```
$('input:disabled').addClass('red');
```